# asp.net webforms Bundling and Minification not working with .net framework 4.0

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms, iis-7, .net-4.0

i have configure my project accroding to below tutorial

http://igorzelmanovich.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/using-aspnet-bundling-and-minification.html

i have installed all required package.

that all worked well.

and i also see bundling in chrome devloper tool like below
http://localhost/JavaScriptLibraries/jQuery/js?v=ifJSwr5Uh90QHbVi_neoWhazO4vJ9Agrw2Mnj7L8myw1

but its giving error in console

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/JavaScriptLibraries/jQuery/js?v=ifJSwr5Uh90QHbVi_neoWhazO4vJ9Agrw2Mnj7L8myw1

so my question is 
this bundling and minification support in .net framework 4.0 ?

or i have to updagrad to 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<system.webServer>
 <modules>
   <remove name="BundleModule" />
   <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
 </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

above config in web config resolve my issue.